# Changing ALL System Fonts in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, windows-registry, desktop-customization

I had a quick question about altering fonts in Windows 7 I was hoping someone could give me a hand with. I have a touch of OCD when it comes to consistency and am having trouble changing the system fonts globally on my machine. I have changed 80% or so of them through the registry entry (found here):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
  ; Created by: Shawn Brink
  ; http://www.sevenforums.com
  ; Tutorial: Fonts - Change

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
  "Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
  "Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
  "Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
  "Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
  "Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
  "Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
  "Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"=""

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
  "Segoe UI"="CUSTOM_FONT_NAME"
```

The only issue I’m having is that the font is not adjusted in a few other places. For example, if I right-click on a file and look at the properties window, the font is still the default system font. The following is an example:

[image]

I’ve changed both the registry entry and the window fonts under “Personalization” to what I want but can’t seem to figure out how to change this font. I’d be eternally (or close to it) grateful to anyone who knows how to alter this font.

**Edit:** Shortly after posting this I found the exact registry edit I was looking for:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.sevenforums.com
; Tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1175-fonts-change.html


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"MS Shell Dlg 2"="Tahoma"
"MS Shell Dlg"="Tahoma"
```

Comment: If you found an answer that suits you, feel free to write it as an answer in the field below. This will help other people with a similar problem find this question and the answer embedded within. Check the [about] for more info on how Super User works.

Answer (score 4):

As you found your answer, repeated below, then adding your solution as an answer and marking it as the correct answer means this question will no longer appear on the "unanswered" section of this site.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.sevenforums.com
; Tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1175-fonts-change.html


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"MS Shell Dlg 2"="Tahoma"
"MS Shell Dlg"="Tahoma"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're more concerned w/ using same / similar fonts everywhere vs. enlarging them?

I found what you show in the registry for a default system font.
As you said, personalization options only let you change so much.
Some say they've had success on fonts using Skinstudio (SKS). 
Fonts & SKS are discussed a good bit on [WindowBlinds forum](https://forums.stardock.com/482541)

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend changing all the system fonts in windows.
Some applications may not display as anticipated.
 You do not need to use the registry as in Control Panel click on the "Fonts" Icon and you will find a wealth of information and adjustments to all fonts on your machine and a link to load more fonts.
 You can add fonts, hide fonts, delete fonts even adjust clear type text properly. (Fonts Icon Control Panel).

Comment: I believe the question is about "how to do something?" vs "is it good to do sth?"  .  On top of that Fonts in Control Panel doesn't offer a single bit of information about how to substitute fonts.

Answer (score -1):

There's a thread here on how to change fonts used in Windows default applications like Sticky Notes in Windows 7.

I imagine you can follow similar steps and set all fonts to the same .ttf file following these instructions: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a75ad434-fc85-4840-8798-f2205cc026d4/how-to-change-sticky-note-font?forum=w7itproui

*edit added instructions to be relevant*

With some modifications with that font, you can use other fonts as to change the default font in Windows applications.

1. Start
2. Run - type `regedit`
3. Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
4. on right pane find one font you don't want to view such as "Segoe Print (TrueType)" and "Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)" - double click (don't forget to change both - one by one)

optional - you can delete other Segoe fonts - select(one click), press Del, press Yes

5. Change the value(double click on font) to the file name of any other font that you wish to use that is already installed - for "times new roman" it should be times.ttf .
6. Restart the computer.

*end edit*

This should have a similar effect to change most, if not all of your computer fonts from this tutorial. You will have to reset your computer to see the changes, which will mean probably some back and forth tweaking and testing.

Comment: Does this method negate the need to perform font subtitution? I'd like to remain able to see and use Segoe UI.