# Troubling Changing System Font to a Foreign Font Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, desktop-customization

I'm having trouble trying change my Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (English Version) system font to a another Chinese font I downloaded, 
The font I'm trying to change to my system font is this:
http://www.freechinesefont.com/traditional-ar-tianniu-b5-download/

However when I try the normal method via This:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/change-windows-fonts#1TC=windows-7

The font doesn't appear as an option, because of its font name is in Chinese characters.

I've tried the registry way:
[Changing ALL System Fonts in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/794505/changing-all-system-fonts-in-windows-7)

However, it doesn't change the start menu or desktop icon fonts and much of the interface fonts. Some interface fonts have changed as desired though.
Need help changing the rest. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried changing the font name from from chinese characters to english characters and then the normal method above?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to change the "display language" (as referred by Microsoft). Here is a link that might help you.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-or-change-a-display-language